# Launch android app from specific browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with starting my android application from browser.
I specify following code in my manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:path="/store" android:host="play.google.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

When I try to launch app from default browser on Android 2.2 all works fine: a dialog appears asking what we would like to use to handle the intent (browser or my custom app). But when I try it from firefox or chrome on Android 4.0.1, browser handles url  and opens web-page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that chrome is now not allowing other applications to catch custom schemas and instead handling them all itself. I believe this is a recent chrome update. I know I'm looking into this now as it breaks one of my apps.

Comment: did you find solution for this? I am trying to launch android app using hidden iframe, which works in stock and firefox browser but stopped working on chrome from last many days.

Answer (score 0):

You register your Intent-Filter on `android.intent.action.VIEW`. You should look in your logcat, which `ACTION` will send when you use firefox or chrome.

Comment: Hi, JaMic! I checked logcat when I used chrome on Android 4.0.1 and default browser on Android 2.2. When I'm typing url in default browser a dialog for choice app is present and logcat is empty.Logs are present after choice app from dialog. In chrome dialog isn't present and logs are empty. Do you have any idea why chrome not shows dialog and opens a web-page?